# import List in haskell

Tags: visual-studio, haskell

I'm trying to work with lists in Visual Haskell Studio, but it doesn't recognize import Sytem.List neither does it recognize import List.
How can I use simple list functios in VHS?
Urgent!
Thank you so much in advance!!!

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean:

```
import Data.List
```

I suggest always using `Data.*` for anything in the `Data` libraries, rather than regular `List` or `Ratio`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I will point out that Visual Haskell Studio is an (outdated) IDE plugin, and not an implementation of Haskell itself. I suspect the underlying implementation is GHC.

Second, List is in Data.List, not System.List. If you don't know where a library is, but you know of a function that exists in that library, you can use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), which appears to be down right now. An alternative you can use while Hoogle is down, is [Hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html).